# Foreground service being killed on Chinese OEMs like Vivo

Tags: android, background, foreground-service

One of core functionalites of our app, requires us to track the drivers all the time in working hours. The foreground service, used for fetching location updates, is being killed in some chineese devices like vivo. I am aware of these custom OS killing services to save battery, I was wandering has there been any recent development on this topic. Is there any way to make sure that the service won't be killed on most devices and If I ask user to give auto start functionality, is there any way to check if the user has given the permission?

I have started the service sticky and obtained wake lock to prevent against doze mode. Also, Showing dialog to obtain auto start functionality if available for manufacturer.

Comment: I had a service like this running on my phone, while it had a list of services to not kill there was no way to add anything to this list (it was very badly coded), the only solution I found that worked was to use ADB to uninstall the package.

Comment: Usually on these devices there is a way for the user to add your app to a list of "protected apps" or "apps allowed to run in the background" or something like that. You will need to request that the user manually add your app to this list.

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes, I am aware of that! 
But is there any way to detect whether your app has been whitelisted for background apps by the user?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.

Comment: @Wolfie Did you find any solution. I am struggling with this same problem

Comment: @RSumanRadhakrishnan The only solution is to handle this for each phone. So, I had to build it out. It is not perfect but works for most phones. I am building out a library, "BatteryPermissionHelper", for this. I have added some core code, that you can use meanwhile, https://github.com/WaseemSabir/BatteryPermissionHelper

Answer (score 0):

WakeLock doesn't really help on last Android versions unless you request [REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) permission before acquiring.